# Detecting a text-selection event in GWT? (equilivent of this javascript)

Tags: events, gwt, selection, selectionchanged

I am trying to detect when text is selected in a GWT app.
On Pc's this is easy, but on touch devices its providing hard.

I found this bit of javascript that at least works in newer webkits/blink.

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {

var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "selectedText"+selectedText;

}, false);"
```

Doesn't help with Firefox, but I can live with that for the moment.

How would I replicate this javascript in gwt?

I tried;

```
mainBody.addHandler(new SelectionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent event) {
            Log.info("change detected");
            String selected = mainBody.getSelectedText();

            Log.info("selected="+selected);

            if (selected.length()>10){
                Window.alert("selection="+selected);
            }


        }
        }, SelectionEvent.getType());
```

(where MainBody is a textarea widget)

But doesn't seem to work. Do I need to use a native javascript snippet? (not sure how to do that with a handler, however)

Thanks,

Comment: `SelectionHandler` and `SelectionEvent` are not about **text** selection, they're _logical_ events about selected **items** (selected tab in a tab panel for instance)

Comment: ah, ok, it was a complete guess on my part that.